# using the as.POSIXlt function

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr

I am currently using the "economics" dataset in `ggplot2` package. I have been told to try this code, and it works, but I do not understand the first line (how does this date conversion function work - I have seen in the vignette that it is supposed to change the timezone, but it doesn't seem to be used to that purpose here ? what does x refer to ?) and I would be grateful for any help!

```
year <- function(x) as.POSIXlt(x)$year + 1900


ggplot(economics, aes(unemploy / pop, uempmed)) +
  geom_path(colour = "grey50") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = year(date)))
```

Comment: `1900` seems to be expressed in seconds, i.e `as.POSIXlt(x)$year + 1900 seconds`

Comment: 1900 is not seconds. POSIXlt class year value is stored using [a base index value of 1900](https://www.neonscience.org/resources/learning-hub/tutorials/dc-convert-date-time-posix-r). For instance `as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())$year` will return  you the value 122. You need to add back 1900 to get back the year 2022 (the year for current system time).

Answer (score 2):

The `as.POSIXlt` function converts an existing date or date-time (in a variety of different formats) into an object of class "POSIXlt". This is really just a list with different components such as year, month, day, etc.

We can see this with a simple example:

```r
my_date <- as.POSIXlt("2022-07-20")

unclass(my_date)
#> $sec
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $min
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $hour
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $mday
#> [1] 20
#> 
#> $mon
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $year
#> [1] 122
#> 
#> $wday
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $yday
#> [1] 200
#> 
#> $isdst
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] "GMT"
```

We can use `$` notation to extract any of these elements just as we can with a normal `list`:

```
my_date$year
#> [1] 122
```

Since the year is represented as an integer relative to 1900, adding 1900 to the result simply returns the year as an integer:

```
my_date$year + 1900
#> [1] 2022
```

So your `year` function will simply extract the year as an integer from a date or date-time in s variety of formats. In the case of your plot code, it is simply extracting the year from the `date` column.

The `year` function you have shown is essentially identical to the `year.default` function in the `lubridate` package, except you don't need to load in an extra package:

```r
lubridate:::year.default
#> function (x) 
#> as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$year + 1900
#> <bytecode: 0x000001ba60f19bf8>
#> <environment: namespace:lubridate>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Something strange is that RStudio does not suggest anything when one types `my_date$`

Comment: @Julien I think this is because it is an S3 class. If you `unclass` it, you will see autocomplete works on the resulting list.